# Measure all distances return shortest value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one table with a list of stores, approximately 100 or so with lat/long. The second table I have a list of customers, with lat/long and has more than 500k.

I need to find the closest store to each customer. Currently I am using the geography data type with the STDistance function to calculate the distance between two points. This is functioning fine, but I am getting hung up on the most efficient ways to process this.

Option #1 - Cartesian join Customer_table to Store_table, process the distance calculation, rank the results and filter to #1.  Concern with this is that if you have a 1 million row customer list, and 100 stores, you are created a 100 million row table and the rank function then thereafter may be taxing.

Option #2 - With some dynamic sql, create a pivoted table that has each customer in the first column, and each subsequent column has the calculated distance to each branch. From there, I can unpivot and then do the same rank/over function described in the first.

EXAMPLE

```
CUST_ID     LAT     LONG     STORE1DIST     STORE2DIST     STORE3DIST
1           20.00   30.00    4.5            5.6            7.8
2           20.00   30.00    7.4            8.1            8.5
```

I'm not clear which would be the most efficient, and will keep the DBA's from wanting to come find me.

Thanks for the input in advance!

Comment: Do you have the option of using a tool like KNIME, which has a node (calculate distance matrix) specifically for accomplishing this?

Comment: @Andy In this case probably not, as we have a pretty intense software acquisition/review process. But something I'd like to look further at for future projects. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Do you want to find the closest store? Or the closest *three* stores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the data into multiple rows for each store distance then use simple pivot (Group by) to get the minimum value of StoreDistance.

```
select CUST_ID, MIN(STOREDIST) StoreDistance, MIN(STORES) StoreName
from 
(select CUST_ID, LAT, LONG, STORE1DIST, STORE2DIST, STORE3DIST from Cus/*Your table*/) p
UNPIVOT
(
STOREDIST FOR STORES IN (STORE1DIST, STORE2DIST, STORE3DIST)
) as unpvt
Group by CUST_ID
```

This will give you the result as:

```
CUST_ID StoreDistance   StoreName
-----------------------------------
1       4.5             STORE1DIST
2       7.4             STORE1DIST
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation on my job. I use a distance function like this (returns kms, use `3960*` to return miles):

```
CREATE Function MySTDistance(@lat1 float, @lon1 float, @lat2 float, @lon2 float)
returns smallmoney
as
    return IsNull(6373*acos((sin(radians(@lat1))*sin(radians(@lat2)))
                           +(cos(radians(@lat1))*cos(radians(@lat2))*cos(radians(@lon1-@lon2)))),0)
```

then you look for the closest store by doing something like...

```
select C.Cust_Id
    ,Store_id=
        (select top (1) Store_id
           from Store_Table S
          order by dbo.MySTDistance(S.lat, S.long, C.lat, C.long)
        )
from Customer_Table C
```

Now you have each customer id with his closest store id. It's quite fast with a huge volume of customers (at least in my case).